# integer as sum of three binomials

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Prove that for any nonnegative integer $n$ $\exists x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0\leq x<y<z$ so
$$n=\binom{x}{1}+\binom{y}{2}+\binom{z}{3}$$

Please give me a hint, I don't have any idea.

Comment: Does not work for $n=1$.

Comment: @Martigan , it works:  x = 0, y = 1, z = 3

Comment: $0!=1$, hence it does not work....

Comment: @Martigan The definition is sometimes extended to be that it equals zero any time the lower number is larger than the top number. That allows Pascal's triangle to be surrounded by zeroes. Also the factorial way to calculate a binomial coefficient is not the only way, nor is it even necessarily part of the definition.

Comment: If we take the convention of the binomial being $0$ if the numerator is inferior to the denominator, then yes.

Comment: For the OP, I'm feeling induction would be a good thing to try. Notice that the first part of the sun can only be $0$ or $1$ and the second part can be incremented by $1$ by incrementing $y$ by $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $z_m={m\choose 3}$ for all $m$. Difference $z_{m+1}-z_{m}=\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$. We choose such $m$, that $z_m$ is maximal, non exceeding $n$.
The most difference $n_y=n-z_m$ we would have to cover, is $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}-1$.
Now we choose $y_k={k\choose 2}$ to be maximal, non exceeding $n_y$. Note that maximal $k$ could be $m-1$, since $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}-1$ is the maximal value for $n_y$ (i.e. it can't be $\ge\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$). Analogically, $y_{k+1}-y_k-1=k-1$ is the maximal value to cover with $x$.
So, we select $y=k$ and $z=m$.

Answer (score 2):

Easy to see that
$$
1 = {x_1 \choose 1}+{y_1 \choose 2}+{z_1 \choose 3}
$$
where $x_1 = 0$, $y_1 = 1$, $z_1 = 3$.

Now suppose
$$
i = {x_i \choose 1}+{y_i \choose 2}+{z_i \choose 3}
$$
where $0 \leq x_i < y_i < z_i$. We want to decide $0 \leq x_{i+1} < y_{i+1}<z_{i+1}$ such that
$$
i + 1 = {x_{i+1} \choose 1}+{y_{i+1} \choose 2}+{z_{i+1} \choose 3}
$$

---

I provide a procedure to decide $x_{i+1}, y_{i+1}, z_{i+1}$ below.

- **if $x_i < y_i - 1$**

Let $x_{i+1} = x_i + 1, y_{i+1} = y_i, z_{i+1} = z_i$. Easy to see that the sum increment $1$.

- **if $x_i = y_i - 1\textbf{ and }y_i < z_i - 1$**

Let $x_{i+1} = 0, y_{i+1} = y_i + 1, z_{i+1} = z_i$. We have
\begin{align}
&{z_{i+1} \choose 3} + {y_{i + 1} \choose 2}+{x_{i+1} \choose 1} - {z_i \choose 3} - {y_i \choose 2}-{x_i \choose 1}\\
=& {z_i \choose 3} + {y_i + 1 \choose 2}+{0 \choose 1} - {z_i \choose 3} -{y_i \choose 2} - {y_i - 1 \choose 1} \\
=& \frac{(y_i + 1)y_i}{2} + 0 - \frac{y_i(y_i - 1)}{2} - (y_i - 1)\\
=& 1
\end{align}

- **if $x_i = y_i - 1\textbf{ and }y_i = z_i - 1$**

Let $x_{i+1} = 0, y_{i+1} = 1, z_{i+1} = z_i + 1$. We have
\begin{align}
&{z_{i+1} \choose 3} + {y_{i + 1} \choose 2}+{x_{i+1} \choose 1} - {z_i \choose 3} - {y_i \choose 2}-{x_i \choose 1}\\
=& {z_i + 1 \choose 3} + {1 \choose 2}+{0 \choose 1} - {z_i \choose 3} -{z_i - 1 \choose 2} - {z_i - 2 \choose 1} \\
=& \frac{(z_i + 1)z_i(z_i - 1)}{6} + 0 + 0 - \frac{z_i(z_i-1)(z_i-2)}{6} - \frac{(z_i - 1)(z_i - 2)}{2} - (z_i - 2)\\
=& \frac{z_i(z_i - 1)}{2} - \frac{(z_i-1)(z_i - 2)}{2} - (z_i - 2)\\
=& 1
\end{align}

Note that the procedure guarantees $0 \leq x_{i+1} < y_{i+1} < z_{i+1}$.